# Loop through queries of different length

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using zip to loop through the results of two queries simultaneously. However in some cases the results are not of equal length. In those cases I want to set the values of the query that ends first to 0. It is always the occupancy_agency that ends first as it is a subset of the first query. Specifically it is `occupancy_agency_y['supply']` and `occupancy_agency_y['available']`. I've tried to come up with a solution but couldn't figure out how to combine it with `zip` that allows me to loop through both results at the same time.

```
def occupancy_data(area_id, description, period, agency_id):  
    occupancy = Occupancy.objects.filter(description=description) \
        .values('start_date') \
        .annotate(supply_total=Sum('supply')) \
        .annotate(available_total=Sum('available')) \
        .order_by('start_date')

    occupancy_agency = Occupancy.objects.filter(description=description, agency_id=agency_id) \
        .values('start_date',) \
        .annotate(supply=Sum('supply')) \
        .annotate(available=Sum('available')) \
        .order_by('start_date')


    x = []
    _input = occupancy.values('start_date')
    for row in _input:
        x.append("Uge " + str(int(row['start_date'].strftime("%V"))))

    y = []
    for occupancy_y, occupancy_agency_y in zip(occupancy, occupancy_agency):
        comp_supply = (occupancy_y['supply_total'] - occupancy_agency_y['supply'])
        comp_available = (occupancy_y['available_total'] - occupancy_agency_y['available'])

        occupancy_combined = ((comp_supply - comp_available) / comp_supply)

        y.append(occupancy_combined)
    return {'x': x, 'y': y}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools` provides a [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) function that does exactly this...

```
for occupancy_y, occupancy_agency_y in zip_longest(occupancy, occupancy_agency, fillvalue=0):
    ...
```

Or, perhaps:

```
for occupancy_y, occupancy_agency_y in zip_longest(occupancy, occupancy_agency, fillvalue={}):
    comp_supply = (occupancy_y['supply_total'] - occupancy_agency_y.get('supply', 0))
    comp_available = (occupancy_y['available_total'] - occupancy_agency_y.get('available', 0))

    occupancy_combined = ((comp_supply - comp_available) / comp_supply)

    y.append(occupancy_combined)
```

Comment: Awesome:-) I had no idea the solution would be so simple. I love Python and StackOverflow! Your first solution gave me a "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable", but the second worked perfectly. Thanks!